# unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'QPoint' and 'QPointF' in pyqt6

Tags: pyqt6

I have an application built on pyqt6 and wanted to add a feature ( displaying a panorama image),
so I found this code on the internet to display panorama image using pyqt5.
can someone help me convert it to pyqt6?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Panoramic(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, imagePath):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.CrossCursor)
        # keep a reference of the original image
        self.source = QtGui.QPixmap(imagePath)
        self.pano = QtGui.QPixmap(self.source.width() * 3, self.source.height())
        self.center = self.pano.rect().center()
        # use a QPointF for precision
        self.delta = QtCore.QPointF()
        self.deltaTimer = QtCore.QTimer(interval=25, timeout=self.moveCenter)
        self.sourceRect = QtCore.QRect()
        # create a pixmap with three copies of the source;
        # this could be avoided by smart repainting and translation of the source
        # but since paintEvent automatically clips the painting, it should be
        # faster then computing the new rectangle each paint cycle, at the cost 
        # of a few megabytes of memory.
        self.setMaximumSize(self.source.size())
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self.pano)
        qp.drawPixmap(0, 0, self.source)
        qp.drawPixmap(self.source.width(), 0, self.source)
        qp.drawPixmap(self.source.width() * 2, 0, self.source)
        qp.end()

    def moveCenter(self):
        if not self.delta:
            return
        self.center += self.delta
        # limit the vertical position
        if self.center.y() < self.sourceRect.height() * .5:
            self.center.setY(self.sourceRect.height() * .5)
        elif self.center.y() > self.source.height() - self.height() * .5:
            self.center.setY(self.source.height() - self.height() * .5)
        # reset the horizontal position if beyond the center of the virtual image
        if self.center.x() < self.source.width() * .5:
            self.center.setX(self.source.width() * 1.5)
        elif self.center.x() > self.source.width() * 2.5:
            self.center.setX(self.source.width() * 1.5)
        self.sourceRect.moveCenter(self.center.toPoint())
        self.update()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.mousePos = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() != QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            return
        delta = event.pos() - self.mousePos
        # use a fraction to get small movements, and ensure we're not too fast
        self.delta.setX(max(-25, min(25, delta.x() * .125)))
        self.delta.setY(max(-25, min(25, delta.y() * .125)))
        if not self.deltaTimer.isActive():
            self.deltaTimer.start()


    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.deltaTimer.stop()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        qp.drawPixmap(self.rect(), self.pano, self.sourceRect)

    # resize and reposition the coordinates whenever the window is resized
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.sourceRect.setSize(self.size())
        self.sourceRect.moveCenter(self.center)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Panoramic('pano5.jpg')
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is what I tried to do.

changed QtCore.Qt.CrossCursor to QtCore.Qt.CursorShape.CrossCursor

changed QtCore.Qt.LeftButton to QtCore.Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton

changed sys.exit(app.exec_()) to sys.exit(app.exec())

now I reached the point of getting this error

'line 32, in moveCenter
self.center += self.delta
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'QPoint' and 'QPointF''

and could not find a way to work around it in pyqt6

Comment: Well, it's pretty clear (and I'm surprised that it worked before): QPoint and QPointF are not interchangeable. You either convert the center to a QPointF (`self.center = QPointF(self.pano.rect().center())`), or you convert the delta to a QPoint (`self.center += self.delta.toPoint()`).

Comment: @musicamante thanks you so much, converting delta to a Qpoint worked nicely.

Comment: after that i got this error 'self.sourceRect.moveCenter(self.center.toPoint())
AttributeError: 'QPoint' object has no attribute 'toPoint' 'in `self.sourceRect.moveCenter(self.center.toPoint())` but it was a quick fix just changed it to `self.sourceRect.moveCenter(self.center)`

Answer (score 0):

Here are the changes that solved my issue:

Changed `self.center = QPointF(self.pano.rect().center()))` to `self.center += self.delta.toPoint())`.

and changed `self.sourceRect.moveCenter(self.center.toPoint())` to `self.sourceRect.moveCenter(self.center)`.

Now the code is successfully converted from pyqt5 to pyqt6.